# CSOM Form based authentication Security issue

Tags: client-object-model, security, forms-authentication

I'm new in sharepoint development, I was looking for authenticating users via CSOM by using forms based authentication and I found below code.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://myserver/");
  FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo login = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo("bill", "password");
  ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
  ctx.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = login;
```

However, when I look in to the request from fiddler, I saw that password is sent to the authentication.asmx directly(not encrypted).

Is there a way to encrypy these sensitive data before passing the xml request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For FBA, you need to make sure the site is using SSL.

Comment: For FBA, it is the answer. If you do not want to pass the credentials in the clear, you must encrypt the transport with FBA.